# Get posts from custom post type where less than and equal to given post_id and checks if the post contain given tag_slug__in?

Tags: wordpress

i have created custom post type and i added 100 posts.  I need to select the posts from 1 to 3(note 3 is the **post_id**) and need to check with that select posts which are have post tag slug 'food'.  it is possible with get_posts method or i need a custom Query?

Comment: you mean post id in 1, 2 and 3 ?

Comment: yes.. post_id 1 to 3 . if i give post_id 50 then 1 to 50.